# Linux(Ubuntu)のディレクトリ構造について教えてください

Tags: linux

`/var` ディレクトリについて教えてください。

まず `/home/vagrant` にいて、そこで `ls -la` を実行しても `var` ディレクトリは存在しない(表示されない)のですが、`cd /var` とコマンドを実行すると、`var` ディレクトリに移動することができます。

なぜ、`/home/vagrant` にいるときに `ls -la` を実行しても `var` ディレクトリは存在しない(表示されない)のに、`cd /var` とコマンドを実行すると `var` ディレクトリに移動することができるのでしょうか？

また、`/var` ディレクトリはどこに存在しているのでしょうか？
ご教示の程、何卒宜しくお願いします。

**・「var」ディレクトリは存在しない(表示されない)**

```sh
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty:~$ pwd
/home/vagrant
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty:~$ ls -la
total 60
drwxr-xr-x  9 vagrant vagrant 4096 May 15 15:39 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root    root    4096 Jul 21  2015 ..
-rw-------  1 vagrant vagrant  821 Jun 11 04:10 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--  1 vagrant vagrant  220 Jul 21  2015 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--  1 vagrant vagrant 3829 May 15 15:09 .bashrc
drwxrwxr-x  3 vagrant vagrant 4096 May 15 15:19 .bundle
drwx------  2 vagrant vagrant 4096 May 15 13:23 .cache
drwxrwxr-x  3 vagrant vagrant 4096 May 15 14:28 .gem
-rw-r--r--  1 vagrant vagrant  675 Jul 21  2015 .profile
drwxrwxr-x 12 vagrant vagrant 4096 May 15 14:15 .rbenv
drwx------  2 vagrant vagrant 4096 May 15 13:23 .ssh
drwxrwxr-x  3 vagrant vagrant 4096 May 15 15:29 .vim
-rw-------  1 vagrant vagrant  696 May 15 15:39 .viminfo
-rw-rw-r--  1 vagrant vagrant  402 May 15 15:37 .vimrc
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty:~$
```

**・「var」ディレクトリに移動できる**

```sh
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty:~$ pwd
/home/vagrant
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty:~$ cd /var
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty:/var$ ls -la
total 44
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root   4096 Jul 21  2015 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 root root   4096 May 15 13:23 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 May 31 06:25 backups
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root   4096 May 15 15:04 cache
drwxr-xr-x 41 root root   4096 May 15 15:04 lib
drwxrwsr-x  2 root staff  4096 Apr 10  2014 local
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      9 Jul 21  2015 lock -> /run/lock
drwxrwxr-x 10 root syslog 4096 Jun 11 06:25 log
drwxrwsr-x  2 root mail   4096 Apr 16  2014 mail
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Apr 16  2014 opt
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      4 Jul 21  2015 run -> /run
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root   4096 Jul 21  2015 spool
drwxrwxrwt  2 root root   4096 May 15 13:42 tmp
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty:/var$
```

**※追記**

**自分のPCにいるときの「var」ディレクトリの中身**

```sh
tanakatakeshi-no-MacBook-Pro:vagrant tanakatakeshi$ cd /var
tanakatakeshi-no-MacBook-Pro:var tanakatakeshi$ ls -la
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  24 root       wheel       816  2 18  2014 .
drwxr-xr-x@  6 root       wheel       204  2 18  2014 ..
drwx------   2 root       wheel        68  8 25  2013 agentx
drwxr-xr-x   8 daemon     wheel       272  2 18  2014 at
drwx------  47 root       wheel      1598  6 10 22:18 audit
drwx------   2 root       wheel        68  8 25  2013 backups
drwxr-xr-x  59 root       wheel      2006  6 18 09:25 db
drwxr-xr-x   2 root       sys          68  8 25  2013 empty
drwxr-xr-x   5 root       wheel       170  8 17  2015 folders
drwxr-x---   2 _jabber    _jabber      68  8 25  2013 jabberd
drwxr-xr-x   3 root       wheel       102  8 25  2013 lib
drwxr-xr-x  90 root       wheel      3060  6 19 01:26 log
drwxrwxr-x   3 root       mail        102  9 10  2015 mail
drwxr-xr-x   3 root       wheel       102  2 18  2014 msgs
drwxr-xr-x   2 root       wheel        68  8 25  2013 netboot
drwxr-xr-x   2 _networkd  _networkd    68  8 25  2013 networkd
drwxr-x---   6 root       wheel       204  5  4 12:47 root
drwxr-xr-x   4 root       wheel       136  8 25  2013 rpc
drwxrwxr-x  25 root       daemon      850  6 19 15:37 run
drwxr-xr-x   2 daemon     wheel        68  8 25  2013 rwho
drwxr-xr-x   7 root       wheel       238  2 18  2014 spool
```

Comment: `ls -la /var` としてみて下さい

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Linux のディレクトリ構造は `/` (ルートと呼びます) を頂点とした木構造になっており、`/var` とは `/` の下の `var` というディレクトリを指します。

一方、`/home/vagrant` は `/` -> `home` -> `vagrant` というディレクトリを指します。

```
/(ルート)
  +-- home
  |    +-- vagrant  <- 今ココにいる
  +-- var
```

`ls -la` コマンドは現在のディレクトリ配下の一覧を表示しますので、現在のディレクトリが `/home/vagrant` の場合は `/` の下にある `var` は表示できません。

`cd /var` コマンドは `/` の下の `var` に移動するので `var` に移動することが出来ます。

`ls -la /` と表示すれば `/` の下のファイルとディレクトリが一覧表示されます。その中に `var` を見つけることが出来ます。

Comment: とてもわかりやすいご説明ありがとうございます！！
やっと理解することができました。ディレクトリ構造、勉強します。
本当にありがとうございました！！

Answer (score 4):

質問の意図を勘違いしていたら申し訳ないのですが、`ls -la`だけだと/home/vagrant配下の一覧が表示されるだけです。
`cd /var`で/varに移動しているので、/var配下が表示されるようになっている、ということで不思議でもなんでもないと思います。

/home/vagrantにいながら/var配下を表示したい場合、argusさんがコメントで書かれているように`ls -la /var`とすれば表示できます。

Comment: 「/home/vagrant」にいるときの「var」ディレクトリの中身と、自分のPCにいるときの「var」ディレクトリの中身が違うのは、これは普通のことなのでしょうか？ また「var」ディレクトリというのは、元々どこに存在するディレクトリなのでしょうか？ (vagrantの中でなく自分のMacPcの中にいるディレクトリなのでしょうか？)
Linux初心者のためお手数お掛けし申し訳ありません。

Comment: Yuki Inoueさんが書かれているように、自分のPCで表示した`/var`とvagrantで表示した`/var`は別物です。varディレクトリはUNIX系のOSではルート直下にあるのが普通です。なので、macのルート直下に`/var`があり、vagrantで立ち上げた仮想OSのルート直下にもvagrantの`/var`があります。

Answer (score 1):

以下の問題点が混在しているように見受けられました。

## 1. UNIX 上の CUI 操作について

何も考えずにホームディレクトリで ls を実行しても `/var` ディレクトリが表示されないのは、 unix 系 OS に対する CUI の使い方の問題で、 linux も vagrant もこの時点では関係ないと思います。 ls コマンドの挙動がよくわからないのであれば、 vagrant などは使わずに、手持ちの mac で端末を起動して、試行錯誤してみるのが、理解への一番の近道だと思います。というのも、 mac も UNIX 系 OS なので、基本的なコマンド(e.g. `ls` )の使い方は linux と同じだからです。

## 2. Vagrant について

vagrant が何をやるかについての齟齬がある様子です。 vagrant は、仮想的な OS を立ち上げたりするのを管理するツールです。 vagrant で立ち上げたゲスト OS は、ホスト (vagrant を起動しているPC, この場合は mac) とか基本的に独立したものになります。なので、ホストとゲストのファイル・ディレクトリが共有されることは基本的にありません。それぞれは別物です。

Answer (score -1):

`pwd`コマンドによってパスを確認します。
それはカレントディレクトリを返します。

パスの書き方には、絶対パスと相対パスがあります。
`/var`これは絶対パスです.`var`は相対パスです。
`cd /var`と実行することは出来ますが、`cd var`は実行できません。
同じように`ls -la`と`ls -la /`でフォルダの有無が確認出来ます。